# Faceted search using Lucene 4.3

Tags: java, lucene, faceted-search

I was checking on Lucene Faceted search and need some guidance. The [official doc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html#facet_indexing)  mentions about

```
DocumentBuilder categoryDocBuilder = new CategoryDocumentBuilder(taxo);
```

But I am unable to find DocumentBuilder and CategoryDocumentBuilder classes in lucene-facet-4.3.0.jar. Most of the online tutorials that I could find also mentions the same steps as in official doc
These are present in an [old version](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_4_0/api/contrib-facet/org/apache/lucene/DocumentBuilder.html)

Any idea what are the equivalent ones in 4.3? Or any help in getting this implemented in 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Just noting down what I got after putting the qn to Lucene Mailing list:

[This is a sample implementation done in 4.3](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_3/lucene/demo/src/java/org/apache/lucene/demo/facet/SimpleFacetsExample.java)